# Linux includes in Windows (ioctl etc.)

Tags: c, linux, windows, io

I have to study and later on work on a code I received from a (currently absent) colleague. Sadly the code includes some linux includes.

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <linux/can.h>
#include <linux/can/raw.h>
```

I already found a replacement for the following ones:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 1
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#else
// unix includes here
    # include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif
```

I tried to find a replacement on Google but failed. :/ Does anyone know the corresponding windows includes or how I might find them?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: If you don't mind pulling in a compatibility layer, try [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), but this only helps for POSIX compliant code, not Linux-specific one. On Windows 10, you might be able to use an [Ubuntu userland](http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-run-run-the-native-ubuntu-desktop-on-windows-10/) instead. Final (and cleanest) option: **port** the code, using native windows API. This won't be done by simply replacing the `#include`s.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will have a look how to port the code by windows API :) If you have any suggestible reads, I would really appreciate them :)

Comment: Looking at what `linux/can.h` provides, I think you might be out of luck here. This seems to be a socket-based implementation of CAN bus (used in cars). I'm not sure, but I doubt a "drop-in" replacement for windows exists.

Comment: ok :) I decided to run Xubuntu on a virtual machine now and then use the Linux IDE provided by the hardware maker :) thank you anyway :)